# JS Regex - non-capturing group not working

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

I am working on a regex filter, because it clutters our code, but I cant get it to stop capturing the tags.

What I want captured is **bold**
<a **class="anchorable" href="https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/paste/#exampleusingpaste_word_valid_elements"**>

I have a working PHP regex for this

```
/((<+[a-z]*\K)+\s)+(.*?)>/g
```

but it doesnt work on JavaScript.
What Ive tried:

```
/(?:(<+[a-z]*)+\s)+(.*?)>/g
```

Ive been testing it on this page https://regexr.com/ (change from PHP regex to JS regex)

Comment: It [is in Group 2](https://regex101.com/r/xfEBfJ/1).

Comment: `\K` does not work in JavaScript. This regex should work for you using look behind `(?<=` and look ahead `(?=`: `/(?<=<[a-z]*\s).*(?=>)/g`